# Java 6 Application Monitoring Recommendations that offer features similar to Prometheus

Tags: java, monitoring, performance-analysis

NOTE:  I am the newest and most junior developer that I know just to give you an idea of my skill level before you read my question.

The company I work for is a victim of its own success.  In 10 years, they have tripled in size in many areas.  However, from a technology standpoint, they are considerably behind.  My team in specific manages a SOAP service written in Java 6 and running on IBM Websphere Application Server 8.5.5.  We wanted to be able to monitor the service to get an idea of how often certain calls were being made, when the application is being used more, when certain methods are being run more than others, etc.  Currently, we have ZERO exposure to any performance metrics from this service.

I started researching application monitoring solutions and quickly realized that it will be hard to find application monitoring options for a Java 6 apps.  I don't mind putting in some work to get the service up and running.  However, I need to try to steer clear of anything that will cost the company because that whole process is a nightmare... just trust me... I can't do that.

So far, I have evaluated Prometheus but in order to export the metrics, I would need to use jetty server and that requires Java 8.  I ran into similar problems with Micrometer and Atlas.

Please note that I do NOT have direct access to the server that these apps are running on... I only have access to the application, Jenkins, and the deployment tool.  Therefore, I can't do anything that requires server-side install either.